# I uninstalled OpenSSH client by mistake. How can I reactivate it?

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh

[See optional feature history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nKUp.png)

I uninstalled openssh client by mistake on Windows10 and now it is not listed in "optional features" anymore. How do I reactivate it?

Comment: Just a suggestion, this kind of questions are not well suited for StackOverflow (which is about programming). Please next time consider other StackExchange network sites like https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I manually setup SSH. Might help someone in the future.

1. Download the latest version of OpenSSH at https://www.mls-software.com/files/setupssh-7.4p1-1.exe
2. Execute the downloaded package
3. Uncheck “Server” in the "Choose Components" screen
4. Select path to install
5. Click **Next** till **Finish**

Open cmd prompt and type ssh to ensure SSH is properly installed.
Ref : https://ittutorials.net/microsoft/windows-10/enable-ssh-windows-10-command-prompt/

Comment: TROJAN                AAAAAAAAa

Answer (score 1):

Today (28 August 2018) I did the same thing as OP on windows10pro 1803. After help from MS help chat, it is now resolved, with SSH Client installed.

This may be the **'nuclear option'** and may have side effects for others, but it worked for me. **I did a system restore to a previous date**, which effectively undid my accidental uninstall of SSH Client.

1. Cmd+R to open Run window,
2. then type *rstrui*
3. then I chose most recent date to restore from.

Required a restart and took about 10 minutes.

Comment: @Meloman, my first ever answer is much better for your edits, thanks!